# Changing Appearance of Controls In UserControl When Disabled

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, silverlight-4.0, styles

I have a user control, which has a `Border` and a `TextBlock` in it.  I want to change the appearance of the control's when the user control is disabled, rather than the default graying out.  How can I setup a style to change the UI of the children when the user control is disabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an implicit style for each of the border and textblock, scoped to your control, with a new Disabled ViewState.

Comment: OK, new to Silverlight, can you send me a link on how to set it up?

Comment: I'll look at this later and post some XAML.